# Report thread progress with a stage first approach

Tags: c#, multithreading, report, progress

I'm willing to report the progress of an intensive task (I/O). I've been reading all the approaches, interface, backGroundWorker, Progress, but no one include any kind of additional info like the current stage of the task. So i wrote this approach and i will be happy if you can give me any kind of feedback, advice or a comment. I'm working in a winforms 4.0 project.

This is the task

```
   class _ThreadTest
        {
        public static  void ReporteProgreso(out int p, out string stage)
        {
            p = 0;
            stage = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                p++;

                switch (p)
                {
                    case 0: stage = "init"; break;
                    case 1: stage = "Loading Data"; break;
                    case 2: stage = "Parsing Data"; break;
                    case 3: stage = "Checking"; break;
                    case 4: stage = "Inserting n Records"; break;
                    case 5: stage = "10%"; break;
                    case 6: stage = "50%"; break;
                    case 7: stage = "70%"; break;
                    case 8: stage = "100%"; break;
                    case 9: stage = "finish"; break;                        

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

And here is how I call it

```
  static void Main()
        {

        //Reportar progreson con OUT
        int p = 0;
        string stage = "";
        _ThreadTest t = new _ThreadTest();
        Thread oThread = new Thread( () => _ThreadTest.ReporteProgreso(out p,out stage) ) ;
        oThread.Start();

        int tmp = 0;
        while (oThread.IsAlive)
        {

            if (tmp != p)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(stage);
                tmp = p;
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Are there any interesting tested, better way to achieve this? Since this approach is working for me, maybe it will not be safe to use in some types of environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx) does exactly what you're trying to do. The second parameter is an object that contains your custom progress report.

That second parameter is in the `UserState` property in the [ProgressChangedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.progresschangedeventargs.aspx) that's passed to your `ProgressChanged` event handler.

The [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.aspx) MSDN topic has a pretty good example. The only thing missing in that example is how to use `UserState`. It's an object, so you need to cast it. So, if your `ReportProgress` call is:

```
ReportProgress(1, "Loading data");
```

Then in your `ProgressChanged` event handler, you'd cast it back to string:

```
// This event handler updates the progress. 
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    resultLabel.Text = (string)e.UserState
}
```

Comment: That will work ok, but maybe i was a little bit aware for dealing with events and delegates. The method i plan to get the progress for is in another layer of my app. As far as i can read, i need to create the event and fire it from the method itself, an then with a subscription, handle it.  
I m writing some code to test if i can implement the backgroundworker into my method and then try to subscribe to the events that it fires. ill update if i can get some working code with it. Thanks for you help @Jim

Answer (score 1):

I Found an approach that work with my needs

In my expensive task, i deal his stage  with something like this

```
public static class ExpensiveTasks
{
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String, int>> ExpensiveTask1(int sleepTime)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(sleepTime);
            yield return new KeyValuePair<String, int>("Reporting Progress", i);
        }
    }
}
```

And then from the Method who calls it, using BackGroundWorker DoWork Event something like this

```
   void bW_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {            
        //var args = e.Argument;             
        BackgroundWorker _bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        foreach (var report in ExpensiveTasks.ExpensiveTask1(100))
        {
            if (_bw.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
            _bw.ReportProgress(report.Value,report.Key);
        }
        e.Result = "The End";           
    }
```

With this approach i can maintain my layered structure 
of course i could send a in some way a reference of BWWorker to the Expensive Task, but maybe it will be under  another layer or module.T So at least with this way to do the thing, has been working for me.

:)